# Insulating the wall

Tags: insulation, walls, new-home

I want to start building my house and wanted to ask for tips on how to do the insulation on the walls. I heard from people how they are doing and here is how it looks from above:
[image]

My questions are:

- want to make sure if that's the way to go.
- is it efficient
- is there better ways of doing it

Place where I live doesn't have all kinds of stuff that you can find in US stores. 
We can find drywall, foam block in different sizes (maybe up to 10 cm), soft foam sheets with thin metal foil, fiberglass.

Update: Outside of bricks are covered with sand plaster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @DMoore I am in Tajikistan.

Comment: What kind of building resources do you have locally available and within your budget? Bricks? Concrete? Foam insulation boards? AAC (porous concrete blocks)? Any wood?

Answer (score 1):

In general you have the right idea with placing insulation between the thermal masses of two brick layers. This will work well in any climate. However, you can make some improvements. Here are a couple I can think of:

- Use thicker insulation. 5cm may not be enough. Shoot for 10 cm. Result: lower heating and cooling bills, greater interior comfort.
- Plaster the interior faces of the blocks/bricks instead of furring them out with wood and drywalling them. Advantage: cheaper and more durable.
- Use AAC blocks instead of your idea. Advantage: if available, simpler, less expensive construction, easier hiding of wiring and plumbing pipes vs furring out and adding drywall.

Comment: On the furring comment it depends how the run electricity over there.  In France we zip through the blocks with a specialized tool.  In Spain we were drywalling everything.